# Cannot Drop Primary Key Constraint in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, database-administration

I couldn't drop a primary key constraint:

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[TableName] DROP CONSTRAINT [PK_TableName]
GO
```

When running the above query, I get this error:

> Msg 3727, Level 16, State 0, Line 5
>   Could not drop constraint. See previous errors.
>
> Msg 845, Level 17, State 1, Line 5
>   Time-out occurred while waiting for buffer latch type 3 for page (1:253130136), database ID 7.

Can someone please suggest a solution?

Comment: within SSMS go to Tools > Options and click on the Designers increase the 30 seconds

Comment: It is already in 30 sec

Comment: I know, I said increase it

Comment: What does the error log tell you?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, the database is damaged.

If you can kick everybody out, you can run [DBCC CHECKDB](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/database-console-commands/dbcc-checkdb-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017).

**edit**

DBCC CHECKDB won't fix the errors but will report, at which point you can decide if you want to fix or restore.

Comment: I wouldn't say most likely here, and DBCC CHECKDB doesn't have to be ran in SINGLE USER mode. Also, running this check won't fix anything, only report errors, and running it with one of the repair modes is overwhelming not advised by the community. Calling microsoft or restoring from a backup should be the go-to actions, if there were corruption.

Comment: @scsimon You're right, of course, which is why I didn't specify any of the "repair" switches. Unfortunately I left that out of the answer, which I've now updated.